# Mental disorders - where to go?

Tags: mental-health, depression, psychologist-psychology, psychiatrist-psychiatry, suicide

I have had mental issues since I was four years old, I'm 16 now. I live in Austria. I have already spent a few months in a psychiatric care, but things don't seem to be getting better, and in face, seemed to get worse. That was last year. And in the last few months, there have been new problems that have surfaced with my psyche and they are getting worse every day.

I already have a therapist but I don't know if she can help me, my parents don't understand. What else could I do to make things better for me? I hope you can help me, if the question is not allowed her you can delete it.

Comment: Have you tried discussing your new issues with your therapist?

Comment: Yes, today. She told me that she doesn't know how to help me. She never had a client with problems like I have and she has no idea how my life coud get better. So what now? @L.B.

Comment: Please see Lucky's answer. And if you feel like you need immediate help, please go to your nearest hospital (even if they do not specialize in mental health), they will help you or find resources that can help you.

Comment: @L.B. already done but that doesn't help me very much. I already have a therapist. If I'm searching for a new one now my health insurance won't pay anymore, then I have to wait a few months again and my parents don't have that much money.

Comment: I believe it is difficult to deal with a doctor who can't help you while having limited options because of your insurance. I don't know the options in Austria, but maybe you could join some form of group therapy if it exists for your type of problem. It might be cheaper and help you  until insurance covers a different therapist. In the meanwhile I hope your therapist will step up and try to help you as much as possible - although the ideal case would be that they have experience with your problem, they can also read about it, consult a colleague and change their approach to fit your needs.

Comment: The last part, however, rests on the therapist's professionalism. Being a healthcare professional myself, I think that one never stops learning in our profession. (In fact I have to research every answer I write here because of the policy on references). However, different people have different views on what their job is. The best thing you can do is to be persistent in looking for help. I am not a legal expert, but perhaps you can make a case with the insurance if the therapist herself says she has no experience with your type of problems.

Comment: @Lucky Unfortunately I don't know any group therapies in my region, also I think that group therapy is not the best for *me*, because "other people" and "me" cannot live very well together. I know that from the psychiatry

Comment: The therapist that you currently have most likely has a network of people whom she reach out to in complicated cases. Even if no one in that network is able to provide direct solutions to the problems you are experiencing, they should still be able to provide some suggestions or recommendations to her on where she could look for additional directions.

Comment: @L.B. I see, you closed this question. How can I edit it, to fit the rules again? Or should I leave it be and don't edit the question?

Comment: @Serafina Reisinger If you can edit it so that it is not a personal question, then it has a chance of being reopened.

Answer (score 2):

[National Alliance for Mental Illness - NAMI (Main Line, PA)](https://namipamainline.org/choosing-the-right-mental-health-professional/) quotes an article from SAMHSA:

> **Therapy is a collaborative process, so finding the right match-someone with whom you have a sense of rapport-is critical.** After you find someone, keep in mind that therapy is work and sometimes can be painful. However, it also can be rewarding and life changing.

In essence, therapy takes time and patience. However, you can (and should) monitor your progress. If you don't feel that you are getting the help you need, you can talk about this to your therapist. This is a great advantage of getting help in person over getting help over the internet: therapy can and should be customised to your needs. For a therapist to do that, they need your help. The best way to help them and your self is to communicate your concerns. However, people are different - both doctors and patients. If after a while you don't think that there is any improvement, you should feel free to look for another therapist. 
When looking for a therapist you should feel free to ask questions. Aside from asking for credentials and fees, Mayo Clinic staff article (also quoted by NAMI) recommends asking about your therapist's:

> ... treatment approach and philosophy, to make sure it suits your style and needs.Whether they specialize in certain disorders or age groups. Some, for instance, work only with adolescents. Others specialize in eating disorders or substance abuse.

A therapist who specialises in your type of problems is more likely to have the necessary experience to help you. Also, since therapy is a sensitive process, finding someone you feel comfortable working with can aid the therapy process.

The important thing is not to give up on therapy and seeking professional help. For tips on finding a therapist that suits you, you might have a look at these:

[How to Find a Therapist](http://www.webmd.com/mental-health/features/how-to-find-therapist#1) - from WebMD

[Finding a Mental Health Professional](https://www.nami.org/Find-Support/Living-with-a-Mental-Health-Condition/Finding-a-Mental-Health-Professional) - from NAMI

[Choosing the Right Mental Health Professional](https://namipamainline.org/choosing-the-right-mental-health-professional/) - NAMI, PA

Comment: Excellent answer! The only thing I would like to add is this: if you are feeling suicidal, please contact the police, an ambulance or find some way to get to a hospital.